# Android NFC Application detection

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I want to use NFC in my Android application. I am able to read and write data using NFC. I want my application to recieve NFC data from a specific application not from all other applications present in the device.

I have used following code for this

```
NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.android.beam")
```

but it sill communicates with application with other package name.

Please help me in this.

Comment: pls refer this link http://www.tappednfc.com/android-nfc-developer-guide/

Comment: aslo this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Comment: is there any solution for this ?

Comment: One solution is the while send the data from ur application we should add the some key. if the message have that key then read the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Android Application Record, you can only make sure that no other app will be launched as a consequence of your NDEF message. YOu cannot prevent that another app -- while that app is in the foreground -- receives NDEF messages you sent. You can also not really prevent your app from receiving NDEF messages not intended for your app. However, you can siginficantly limit what NDEF messages your app receives.

In order to limit the NDEF messages your app should receive, you would first decide on an NDEF record, that you want to use to filter upon. E.g. an NFC Forum external type that is specific to your app (note that the type name must be *all-lowercase*):

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| urn:nfc:ext:example.com:mytype | mydata |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

You could create this using `NdefRecord.createExternal("example.com", "mytype", mydata);`. Next, you would use this record as the *first* record of your NDEF message.

Now, you can create your intent filter to only match that specific record. E.g. in your app's mainfest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
        android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
        android:host="ext"
        android:pathPrefix="/com.example:mytype" />
</intent-filter>
```

Or the intent filters parameter for the foreground dispatch system:

```
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
ndef.addDataScheme("vnd.android.nfc");
ndef.addDataAuthority("ext", null);
ndef.addDataPath("/com.example:mytype", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX);
IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] { ndef, };
```